# Kendo UI inline editing with dynamically change editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have two columns [in this demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OFUkesIl/3)

1. Setting Type (which has drop-down list)
2. Editor (it contains the value of column)

I want to change the the `Editor` column when drop-down list value is changed (from `Setting Type` column). Example, if a user selects ***date*** from drop-down list, the `Editor` column field should change to `date picker`.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I've been stuck with this for a week. Appreciate your help. Here's a demo: [DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/OFUkesIl/3)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to switch to incell edit mode (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable) so that when the editor for the settingDefaultValue is created, the value of settingType is set.

The second option is to bind to the change event of the typeEditor and re-create the editor for settingDefaultValue. Currently, I don't think the grid.refresh() will even be fired, since the grid has a row open for edition. In the typeEditor change event, e.sender will give you the kendoDropDownList, and something like e.sender.element.closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)") will give you the container to put the editor in.

One more remark: use either data-bind="value:YourFieldHere", or a change handler with options.model.set("YourFieldHere", this.value()), but you don't need to do both - setting the YourFieldHere is literally what the [value binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value) does.